# Как правильно записать тег при помоши XMLWriter

Tags: php

есть следующий объект

```
0=> 
   param=>
    name=>'Размер',
    'size'=>15 cм',
1=>
   param=>
       name=>'Размер',
       'size'=>20 cм'
```

надо получить такие теги

15 см
   20 см

пытаюсь сделать так

```
if (is_array($offer->param)) {
        foreach ($offer->param as $name => $value) {
            $writer->writeElement($name, Html::encode($value));
        }
    }
```

получаю

```
<Размер>15 см<Размер>
<Размер>20 см<Размер>
```

Подскажите, как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейший работающий пример:

```
$params = [
    ['name' =>'Размер', 'size'=> '15 cм'],
    ['name' =>'Размер', 'size'=> '20 cм'],
];

$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startElement('core');
foreach ($params as $item) {
    $xml->startElement('param');
    $xml->writeAttribute('name', $item['name']);
    $xml->text($item['size']);
    $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
echo $xml->flush();
```